# Picking a specific element when there is multiple elements of the same type on the page

Tags: java, selenium

Basically what I am trying to do is make a simple bot for the game Satoshi mines. I've gotten all features to work except one, which is bomb detection.

This is the code:

```
WebElement  bomb =      driver.findElement(By.className("game").cssSelector("li[class='tile pressed bomb reveal']"));
```

The problem is that it finds bombs from earlier games, as the page stores all previous game play. So even when there is not a bomb in the current game, it searches the whole page for bombs and finds them so it thinks it's still losing. Any ideas? Clear the webelement cache? I'm not sure how to keep it looking for bombs in only the current game.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `DIV` that is the current game. From what I've seen, the previous games contain the class `faded`

Current game

```
<div class="game practice_game" id="game_xxx" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
```

Previous game

```
<div class="game practice_game faded" id="game_xxx" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
```

So you need a locator that specifies that the element should not contain the `faded` class, e.g. the CSS selector:

```
div.game:not(.faded)
```

From there you can specify the `LI` tags that contain whatever you want.